# GameObject not synced with the colider

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

the box shape collider dosent fit the cup and

[image]

I've tried making the image different dimensions but it dosent work

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a box shape collider, try a [Polygon Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html) for 2D or a [Mesh Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) for 3D. They should fit the bounds of your object more rigidly then a box collider.

Comment: But be careful not to use too many polygon colliders, they are much heavier in the matter of processing.